# Why do I get the error "error: cannot find symbol"?

Tags: java, class

I have two files first one is

**Welcome.java**

```
package com.project;

import com.code.*;

class Welcome {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Test t = new Test();
        System.out.println("the valus is " + t.addition(4,3));
    }
}
```

**Test.java**

```
package com.code;

public class Test {
    private int a;
    private int b;
    public Test() {
        a=2;
        b=3;
    }

    public int addition(int a, int b) {
        return a+b;
    }
}
```

When I compile Welcome.java I got:

> error: cannot find symbol
>
> System.out.println("the valus is " + t.addition(4,3));

Cannot find the reason why ? help please

Edit:

I compile with this command:

`javac com/project/Welcome.java`

Solution:

`javac -cp com/code/* com/project/Welcome.java`

Comment: Please post the full stack trace. Is `com.code` in the classpath?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What does a "Cannot find symbol" compilation error mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25706216/what-does-a-cannot-find-symbol-compilation-error-mean)

Comment: @hoefling have found that link before but doesn't help at all.

Comment: @Martin.B You need every thing to be in public if you're getting a method from another class. Also try an IDE.

Comment: the class is well recognized as the error concerns the function addition and not the class Test.

Comment: And how do you run the program?

Comment: I found the problem it is with the classpath.

Comment: @Martin.B Could you post the solution as a self-answer instead of editing it in and mark it as accepted? See https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer

Answer (score 2):

At Test, the addition method should be public int addition(int a,int b)

Comment: It doesnt change anything.

Comment: Add public to the Test() method as well

Comment: before commenting please try to compile it.

Comment: I actually compiled and run this, it's working :D
use Eclipse or Intelij if you are having problem compiling from cmd, much easier and user freindly